# Sorting records in MySql/php based on near-identical multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

Assume I have a following in a MySql table:
[image]

In this table the values for some of the records (sub 1-7) may identical or near-identical; as in case of Bill, Bush and Kate. 
I want to sort the table based on percentage relatedness among the records. As you can see Bill and Kate are nearly identical, which is followed by Bush. The table should be sorted in this order: Bill, Bush, Gate etc. The table contains over 200 records, with many having near-identical values.
How can this be done in php? Any ideas?

Addition: after viewing responses:
Please note two records:

- 22 + 45 + 67 + 87 + 37 + 54 + 63 = 375
- 45 + 65 + 35 + 45 + 66 + 60 + 59 = 375

add up to 375, but they are NOT identical. I don't want such a situation.

Comment: 1. Normalize your design. A database table is not a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select * 
from your_table
order by abs(sub1 - avg(sub1)) + 
         abs(sub2 - avg(sub2)) + 
         abs(sub3 - avg(sub3)) + 
         abs(sub4 - avg(sub4)) + 
         abs(sub5 - avg(sub5)) + 
         abs(sub6 - avg(sub6)) + 
         abs(sub7 - avg(sub7)) +
```

Answer (score 0):

I should try:

```
SELECT Name, ((Sub1 + Sub2 + Sub3 + Sub4 + Sub5 + Sub6 + Sub7) / 7) AS score FROM table
ORDER BY score DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM <tablename>
ORDER BY (sub1+sub2+sub3+sub4+sub5+sub6+sub7) DESC
```

NOTE: no need to devide by,, because the subjects number will be same for every person